# Set controller of body based on routing in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angularjs-routing

Is there any solution for the set of body tag `ng-controller` value based on `routeChange` in angular js?

I know that it's possible to set from routeProviding like that;

```
$routeProvider
    $routeProvider
       .when('/',{
           templateUrl:'partials/index.html', controller: 'indexCtrl'
       })
       .when('/about',{
           templateUrl: 'partials/about.html', controller: 'aboutCtrl'
    });
});
```

But i wan't to like that something

```
<body ng-app="igoaimalathane" ng-controller="indexCtrl">
```

and when click to about link body controller will set based on which partial view calling by routing.

Comment: No i need :) why i need? : Basically i set every ng-controller in my partial views html files. But i want put some div in main.html, it will be header and header content will change based on controller, because i need to set my ng controller into body dynamically.

Comment: so it's better use `ui-router` and multiple views for it. see [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

Comment: how can i figured out with this? have some example ?